# AS3 Eclipse: How to create template to extends myClass?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, templates

How do I create a template that each time when I create a class that extends `MyClass`, it will automatically add 3 functions.

**EDIT:**
In other words I am trying to implement Abstract functionality in AS3. Assume that `MyClass` have both private and protected methods.

Comment: I see the only way to write own code template and call it every time you need, in Flash Builder: window->preference->flash builder->editors->code template->action script->new. You can use existed templates as an example for template syntax.

Comment: @fsbmain I saw it, just don't know how to write it. This is what the question is about

Comment: ok, I can add an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the only way to write own code template and call it every time you need, in Flash Builder: `window->preference->flash builder->editors->code template->action script->new` and give the name to the template, for instance `myclass`.
You can use existed templates as an example for template syntax.

Template code for `MyClass` child class with three methods:

```
import my.package.MyClass

/**
 * @author ${user}
 */
public class ${enclosing_type} extends MyClass
{
    public function ${enclosing_type}()
    {

    }

    override public function publicMethod():void
    {

    }

    override protected function protectedMethod():void
    {

    }

    override private function privateMethod():void
    {

    }
    ${cursor}
}
```

Usage:

1. Create new "action script file" or "new class",
2. remove all file content
3. type `myclass` and choose from auto-complete options template `myclass`

Comment: I just created new class extending MyClass, and the template did not worked... Are we missing anything?

Answer (score -1):

If you are actually extending `MyClass`, all of `MyClass`'s functions are already available to your descendants. You can also `override` either of them with old header and desired new body, and still be able to call older versions of those functions via `super` qualifier. So, you add those functions to `MyClass` and let them be.

Another way is to make an interface - it's a set of declarations without any function bodies, which you have to `implement` in any class that wants this interface in its content. [A short introduction to interfaces.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#interface) Then your `MyClass` will be an interface, with 3 function declarations in it, and whichever class will be declared as `implements MyClass` will have to provide bodies for these functions.

Check other keywords on that page, including `extends` and `implements`.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: There are no abstract classes in AS3, however you can emulate abstract functions in a normal class via exception throwing:

```
protected function abstractFunction(...params):void {
    throw new Error("Abstract!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for OPP lesson. This is not what I am looking for. I just edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: But I am asking about templates, not this.